# Similar to them, the same as them, or something else?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

Assume that I'm talking about a very special herbal species, then 
which of these sentences is/are correct to use:

> 1. You can't find their similar anywhere else.
> 2. You can't find similar to them anywhere else.
> 3. You can't find the same as them anywhere else.
> 4. You can't find the same anywhere else.

(This is not a multiple choice question, it happened to have four cases purely by accident)

Possibly better suggestions rather than these sentences are also appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide more information why you find this structure difficult or confusing?  Otherwise the question will likely be closed as "proofreading".  Thanks.

Comment: I simply don't know which of them are proper English and which of them are not. Do you think they are all correct? Thanks.

Comment: None of them is very good English, although #4 is probably the closest. But the problem is that you don't explain why you are asking.  Are you trying to figure out "similar to" vs. "same as"?  Or do you want more idiomatic variations on "You can't find anything like this anywhere else"?

Comment: @Andrew I added some further information.

Comment: Thanks.  The main problem is that you should say "the same as **these**" or "similar to **these**" and not "the same as **them**".  But I'm having trouble figuring out the grammar rule for this so I can give you a proper answer.

Comment: None of the sentences are idiomatic. _"You can't find their like anywhere else"_ would have worked a treat 50 years ago, but might puzzle some modern readers. _"You can't find anything like them anywhere else_" is idiomatic but chatty. Why not just say _"They are unique"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

> You can't find their **equal** anywhere else.

[*equal*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/equal)

> 7.*noun*
>   a person or thing equal to another, esp in merit, ability, etc
>   *he has no equal when it comes to boxing*

Answer (score 0):

If you say either -

> You can't find the same species of herbs anywhere else, *or*
>   You can't
>   find the same species of herbs as this anywhere else

then you're emphasizing that you have a specific species of herbs that no one else around has.  You might then go on to claim that your specific species is better.  But you will have to make a separate claim that there aren't other species of herbs which are *similar*.  So your claim in this case is more narrow.

If you say either -

> You can't find a similar species of herbs anywhere else, *or*
>   You
>   can't find a similar species of herbs like this anywhere else

then you are making a broader claim, that not only are your herbs unique in their species, but also in their properties.

Please note that there are other useful answers [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161184/what-is-the-difference-between-same-typical-and-similar) - although this thread was closed for being off-topic, the answers should still be helpful to you.